# Breakpoints not working in .tsx files

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core-mvc

I trying to work with .tsx files inside ASP.NET VNext project. Created .tsx file, that executed without errors, but I can not set a breakpoint inside any method using Chrome. Mappings are exists, but the breakpoint is not working properly. Breakpoint 
works, but stops outside of method in which i sets breakpoint.

My test .tsx file:
    ///

```
interface IAppProps {
    text : String
}


interface IAppState {

}

class IndexPage extends React.Component<IAppProps, IAppState> {

constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
}

getInitialState() {
    var a = 0;
}

render() {
    return (
        <h1>test</h1>
    );
}
```

}

For example, i sets up breakpoint on line "var a = 0;", but Chrome just ignores him and stopping on line:  getInitialState(). And does not let me into the method body.

Answer (score 2):

> but Chrome just ignores him and stopping on line: getInitialState(). And does not let me into the method body.

The ideal solution is to disable sourcemaps and just debug JavaScript. SourceMap support can be spotty. Thats just the (unspoken/ugly) truth of JavaScript developement.